# Java Webclient send null instead a class

Tags: java, webservice-client

Hello I have a Webservice:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getUser")
public Iuser getUser(@WebParam(name = "userid") final String userid) {
    return ejbIuserFacade.getUser(userid);
}
```

the WebService client received the Iuser class fine.

then I have a other method:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "mergeUser")
public boolean mergeUser(@WebParam(name = "iuser") final Iuser iuser) {
    return ejbIuserFacade.mergeUser(iuser);
}
```

simply the same in the other way (from client to server) but the iuser is always null.
I try to recieve with method 1 (all fine) and send the same back with method 2 but iuser is null)

any idea whats wrong?

thanks olaf

Answer (score 2):

Make the IUser implement java.io.Serializable